# Create an instance of a class passing values of list as arguments in Python

Tags: python, list, class, instance-variables

I'm currently try to pass the items of a list create an instance of a class.

My code looks like this

```
args = ["1", "John", "Doe"]

class Token:
    def __init__ = (self, id, name, last_name)
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name

instance1 = Token(args)
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: Token.__init__() missing 3 required positional arguments:
```

I tried changing the type, the data I received comes from a previous for loop that filters the data I need.

**Expecting**

To create an instance with the values of the list and pass them as args.

**Note**

The topple is currently in order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [iterable unpacking operator](https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/):

```py
Token(*args)
```